# Find the index of maximum element in a matrix given sum of rows and columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\d & e &f \\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}$, given sum of each row and column , how to find the index of the maximum element in the matrix? In other words, how to find argmax of joint distribution given all marginals?

Comment: Welcome to the community! It would be better if your efforts are showed to get positive response from the community.

Comment: Do you have any guarantees that the matrix has only one maximal element?  I can imagine a matrix that is symmetric, with the diagonal entries all equal and all maximal, for which it would be impossible to extract the indices of those maxima

Comment: I guess we can assume all elements are unique and also all entries sum to 1.